# Is there a way to see where resources are before unlocked specialized industries in Cities Skylines 2?

Tags: cities-skylines-2

Early in the game before level 3, I don't have access to the specialized industries view where I can toggle to see where each resource is. So by the time I reach level 3 I often realize that I built on top of resources.

What I've done was start another file with everything unlocked to make sure where not to build early. Is there a way to access the resources view early though?